# Would Vikings have worn Fenrir or Jörmungandr as emblem or jewellery?

Tags: vikings

After a discussion I had today about Neopagans and Metalculture it came to modern jewelry often sold with wannabe ancient style carvings of [Fenrir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenrir), [Jörmungandr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6rmungandr) or other beasts of the Nordic pantheon. I could not find any proof against it or supporting it, but are there any artifacts known which show those beings as part of a jewelry, as a ship ornament, on a shield or anything alike?

I highly doubt that it would have been socially acceptable to worship them or show respect in a way of wearing their emblem, but I could not find anything about that so far.

Does anybody know how those deities have been seen or treated in everyday social interaction?

Comment: This ought to be easy; but every search I try is flooded with modern results.  Either there are grave goods that depict these images or not.  (I'm not sure that anyone "worshipped" either of these entities; I think that is a huge misnomer).

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [Norse Rituals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norse_rituals), and the article you link to for individual gods mention the known [picture stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_stone) that depict them. I think together these basically answer your question?

Comment: [Mjölnir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) was clearly depicted in at least one piece of jewelry, not sure about the other gods.

Comment: I know of the picture stones and as well of the use of Mjölnir as emblem. But Mjölnir is the sign of an Æsir, and the picture stones are more to be seen like storytelling or books (or at least I think they are)- The Question is: would it have been socially acceptable for a Viking to wear something like a sign, carved jewellery or ornament that shows a turning towards lets say Fenrir. I did not mean so much worshipping as... lets call it public approvement or respect.

Comment: Wikipedia: _"Gabriel Turville-Petre cites multiple instances where an evil wizard or sorcerer's [fylgja](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fylgja) is a fox, because the image is sly and hiding something, or an enemy's fylgja is a wolf."_ A wolf fylgja might not discernable from Fenrir.